# Ubuntu 22.04 - No sound from frontal case jack AUX

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, audio-jack

I already see all similar post around the web without finding a working solution.

I am in this situation:

- Dual boot: **Windows 11 - Ubuntu 22.04** (audio works normal in Windows 11)
- HW infos:

  - MB: **MAG Z690 TOMAHAWK WIFI DDR4 (MS-7D32)**
  - CPU: **13th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-13700K**
  - GPU: **GeForce RTX 3080 Lite Hash Rate**
- Audio controller:

```
> lspci -v | grep -i audio
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Alder Lake-S HD Audio Controller (rev 11)
01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation GA102 High Definition Audio Controller (rev a1)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. GA102 High Definition Audio Controller
```

- alsa-base.conf:

```
> cat /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf
# autoloader aliases
install sound-slot-0 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-0
install sound-slot-1 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-1
install sound-slot-2 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-2
install sound-slot-3 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-3
install sound-slot-4 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-4
install sound-slot-5 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-5
install sound-slot-6 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-6
install sound-slot-7 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-7

# Cause optional modules to be loaded above generic modules
install snd /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install snd $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-ioctl32 ; /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-seq ; }
#
# Workaround at bug #499695 (reverted in Ubuntu see LP #319505)
install snd-pcm /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install snd-pcm $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-pcm-oss ; : ; }
install snd-mixer /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install snd-mixer $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-mixer-oss ; : ; }
install snd-seq /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install snd-seq $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-seq-midi ; /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-seq-oss ; : ; }
#
install snd-rawmidi /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install snd-rawmidi $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-seq-midi ; : ; }
# Cause optional modules to be loaded above sound card driver modules
install snd-emu10k1 /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install snd-emu10k1 $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-emu10k1-synth ; }
install snd-via82xx /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install snd-via82xx $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-seq ; }

# Load saa7134-alsa instead of saa7134 (which gets dragged in by it anyway)
install saa7134 /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install saa7134 $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist saa7134-alsa ; : ; }
# Prevent abnormal drivers from grabbing index 0
options bt87x index=-2
options cx88_alsa index=-2
options saa7134-alsa index=-2
options snd-atiixp-modem index=-2
options snd-intel8x0m index=-2
options snd-via82xx-modem index=-2
options snd-usb-audio index=-2
options snd-usb-caiaq index=-2
options snd-usb-ua101 index=-2
options snd-usb-us122l index=-2
options snd-usb-usx2y index=-2
# Ubuntu #62691, enable MPU for snd-cmipci
options snd-cmipci mpu_port=0x330 fm_port=0x388
# Keep snd-pcsp from being loaded as first soundcard
options snd-pcsp index=-2
# Keep snd-usb-audio from beeing loaded as first soundcard
options snd-usb-audio index=-2
```

- alsamixer card images:
  [image]

[image]

[image]

- sound settings image (headphone from frontal case AUX jack are correctly detected, but no sound emitted):
  [image]

**I can't understand why rear AUX jack is working perfectly, if I attach my headphone to the rear jack, sound is emitted correctly, whilst frontal AUX jack it just looks dead (same frontal AUX jack that is working perfectly on Windows )**

Someone know what is happening?

Comment: Please don't edit the question to add "solved", etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally was able to solve this issue!

I just discovered the **MAG Z690 TOMAHAWK WIFI** needs an update version of **alsa-ucm-conf** configuration file (`/usr/share/alsa/ucm2/USB-Audio/USB-Audio.conf`).

Check the sound card USB device with:

```
> lsusb | grep -i audio
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0db0:b202 Micro Star International USB Audio
```

In my case `0db0:b202` certify the **MAG Z690 TOMAHAWK WIFI** is the device I have actually installed on my system.

Then execute the following commands in sequence:

```
sudo mv /usr/share/alsa/ucm /usr/share/alsa/ucm.bak
sudo mv /usr/share/alsa/ucm2 /usr/share/alsa/ucm2.bak
curl -L -o alsa-ucm-conf.tar.gz https://github.com/alsa-project/alsa-ucm-conf/archive/refs/heads/master.tar.gz
sudo tar xvzf alsa-ucm-conf.tar.gz -C /usr/share/alsa --strip-components=1 --wildcards "*/ucm" "*/ucm2"
rm alsa-ucm-conf.tar.gz
```

Then **reboot** and now you should have the **front-chassis jack-AUX** working as expected.

You can also check that the updated configuration file (`/usr/share/alsa/ucm2/USB-Audio/USB-Audio.conf`) now supports the **MSI MAG Z690 Tomahawk Wifi** motherboard.

```
> cat /usr/share/alsa/ucm2/USB-Audio/USB-Audio.conf | grep 0db0:b202
        # 0db0:b202 MSI MAG Z690 Tomahawk Wifi
```

Comment: Could you summarize your answer here?  This way, even if the link disappears, your answer remains valid.  This is a general policy here.

Comment: @MarcVanhoomissen DONE ! ;)

Comment: Note that any changes to files in `/usr/share` will be lost when the package that owns it gets updated